# Where to integrate PayU payment gateway

Tags: android, node.js, payment-gateway, payu

I'm developing an android app with server in nodejs(javascript).
I want to know which side should I chose to integrate this gateway in order to make easy and safe payment from either server side(nodejs) or client side (android).

I will be glad to hear any response. Thank u.

Comment: Could you please justify it? :)?http://stackoverflow.com/users/2185245/abhishek

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be in nodejs server. It will help you to secure salt key and reduce the chances of any temper in sending/receiving data. Also all the example of payumoney integration suggest it should be in backend.

There are other advantages as well to keep payment gateway in backend like if you want give discount to your customer, change keys change hashing method then it can be easily done without forcing customer to update their App.

[Here is the link for payu integration sample code](https://www.payumoney.com/websiteintegration.html?utm_source=homepage&utm_medium=footer&utm_campaign=footerlink)